# Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): killed. / Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: conda, environment

I'm installing some project and trying to make environment with `miniconda 3` but i'm getting this error:

```
[INFO] Creating a new conda environment 'ray'...
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): | 
/home/blue/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: line 81:  1924 Killed                  
"$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$cmd" "$@"
[ERROR] Failed to create the conda environment.
```

Can someone please help me deal with this and explain why i'm getting it?

Comment: Please show the command you use.

Comment: ./setup-drone-trainer.sh